# pdf with two signatures not displaying data added after first signature in some PDF readers

Tags: pdf, itext, missing-data

I am creating PDFs with iText. A PDF with two signatures is not displaying data added after the first signature in some PDF readers. Adobe Reader XI, Foxit Reader, Nitro Reader and PDF-XChange Editor all display all data correctly. Free eXPert PDF Reader does not display data added after the first signature. Default PDF Viewer and Gmail PDF Viewer on iPhones do not display data added after the first signature, nor do they display the second signature.

I am trying to determine if this is an iText problem or a PDF Reader problem.

Comment: Apple Preview doesn't even display the signatures! If you are creating PAdES signatures (using iText 5.4 or higher), then the problem is caused by the viewer. If you're using deprecated signatures, then I'm not sure. It depends on whether viewers still want to invest in signature technology that predates PAdES.

Comment: *data added after the first signature* - how is that data added? And is **NeedsAppearances** set to **true** In the PDF.

Comment: Some form fields are populated using iText AcroFields and then the PDF is signed. Some time later, the remaining form fields are populated using iText AcroFields and then the PDF is signed again.

Comment: My PDFs do not have a NeedsAppearances attribute. Not sure how to set NeedsAppearances to true with iText.